# Leak caught by tools performance

Tags: iphone

After running the application with **(Run performance tool -> leak)**, the tool found a memory leak.

1. I run app, view appears and press button for a `tableview` **no leaks**.
2. `tableView` appears and if I don't touch anything **no leaks**.
3. If I select the first `cell` and leave it alone, 3 to 4 seconds later **leak**.

Here is my code:

`didSelectRowAtIndexPath` function is commented out.

```
(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
      {
     cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefaultreuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

    }

    // Configure the cell...
    UITextField *FirstField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 130,     25)];
    FirstField.delegate = self;
    FirstField.tag = indexPath.row;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:FirstField];
    FirstField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyNext;
    [FirstField release];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: In the Instruments view, what kind of object does it say the leak is and whether it happens on your code or in Foundation?

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to create the textfield everytime..Since you are setting a tag for the textfield, you try to get the textfield with tag.

```
UITextField *FirstField = (UITextField *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:indexPath.row];
```

if it is nil, then you create the textfield. This may not be a solution for your problem..But it is definitely optimize the memory usage.

Comment: Nice catch! He should alloc & initWithFrame the UITextField in the "if(cell==nil){}" and add it there. then he can eliminate the second if check since if the cell still exists so does the TextField.

Comment: OK, this is what I did to first find where the leak was coming from. Maybe not the best scholarly way to do it, but I found it! I started by commenting each line, then ran the tool, until UREKA.  This is the line causing the leak [cell.contentview addsubview:firstField];

Comment: The tool says Responsible library: UIKit,  Responsible Frame: UIKeyboardinputManagerClassForInputMode,  Malloc: 128 bytes. Could it be a bug in the SDK???  Could it be that nobody not even apple has run this tool trying to create a tableview??  Not sure as to whats happening.

Comment: Sorry guys, but I can't just do firstField.tag = a number, because when I hit return/next button, it will  not go to the next line.  I have to do firstField.tag = indexPath.row, this has nothing to do with the memory issue at hand.

Answer (score 0):

Wow I can't believe I didn't see that! @Gomathi doesn't know that that is the memory leak.

Follow, even if the cell already exists you are creating a new UITextField and adding it to the  cell. But that does not replace the old TextField because it's not a property it's a subview. You need to set the TextField like so :

```
(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil){
            //Configure the cell
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefaultreuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        UITextField *firstField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 130,     25)];
        firstTextField.tag = 25;// any number will do
        firstField.delegate = self;
        firstField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyNext;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:firstField];
        [firstField release];
    }
    UITextField *firstField = (UITextField *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:25];
    firstField.text = @"row specific content";
    return cell;
}
```

+1 Gomathi you had the seed of the answer.